# Spring Webflux disabling login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Let me shortly describe what problem i am facing right now.

I have configured spring security for webflux application, and i am getting login form prompted, when i try to access the route that doesn't require authentication. The route is /swagger-ui/ and it should get opened without any login forms or whatever.

Below is the code i have within the SecurityWebFilterChain

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    //@formatter:off
    return http
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                    "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui/", "/swagge‌​r-ui",
                    "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()  // Allowed routes for swagger
            .pathMatchers("/api/auth", "/api/auth/**").permitAll() // Allowed routes for auth
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated() // All other routes require authentication
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
            .hsts()
            .includeSubdomains(true)
            .maxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(31536000))
            .and()
            .frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.SAMEORIGIN)
            .and()
            .build();
    //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know, i will appreciate it. Here is the picture what i got in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is even loaded, and what does your debug output tell you, and the browser logs

Comment: @ThomasAndolf well browser console logs are empty, i will try to debug it now.

Comment: But the browser request log, what requests are performed and what requests are red, return statuses, etc

Comment: That diolog box looks like ”basic auth” and is given by the webbrowser and not spring. The path ”/” seems to still have basic auth and someone is requesting that path

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have fixed it accidentally,  .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()    i have removed .disable() from the httpBasic() and apparently its working, but let me chek once again if i have modified something else also.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yeah well besides removing disable(), there is one more thing that i have done and that is in authenticate method which is overriden method from ReactiveAuthenticantionManager. Well in that method, i have created UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with hardcoded values like principal, authorities etc.

Answer (score 11):

I was really annoyed by this issue too. The problem is that by putting `.httpBasic().disable()` in your code you would expect spring to skip basic authentication (that browser window) but it doesn't.

Instead, try providing a `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint` to the `.httpBasic()`.

The most simple one is the [HttpStatusServerEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/HttpStatusServerEntryPoint.html).

***For example in your code change to:***

```
***
return http
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            ***
```

By changing that your server will return a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` HttpStatus instead of that browser window!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like to keep `.httpBasic().disable()` in their code while making the basic login go away I have the following setup that works.

The issue lies in that a default *HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint* is configured as the fallback if there isn't another *ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint*. This entry point returns WWW-Authenticate header with value Basic realm="realm" which prompt the browser to pop the login prompt.

To this disable the entrypoint we cannot just disable httpBasic, but we must configure a custom ServerEntryPoint. I did it through a authentication filter but `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)).and()` should also work.

My setup (which use authentication filter):

```java
http.
        .httpBasic().disable() // Disable Basic Login
        .formLogin().disable() // Disables Form Login
        .logout().disable() // Disables default Logout endpoint
        .authenticationManager(authManager)
        .addFilterAt(createCustomJwtFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/", "/healthcheck").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated();
return http.build();
```

createCustomJwtFilter() method

```java
private static AuthenticationWebFilter createCustomJwtFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager)
{
    AuthenticationWebFilter filter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
    // This line configures the custom entryPoint
    filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(
            new ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)));
    return filter;
}
```

This should also return a 401, while keeping the `httpBasic()` disabled for better code readability.