# Spring Security requests basic authentication even though it's disabled (reactive)

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-test

The following spring security config gives some unexpected behavior.

When making a request to some (non-health-check) endpoint (/user), in the browser and when using curl (via git bash on windows), an unauthenticated request returns an idp redirect as expected.

However, when using the WebTestClient, it returns `401 Unauthorized` with `www-authenticate: [Basic ...]`.

The request for basic authn in this context (and the password generated at startup) are unexpected because I've declared to disable basic authn via `http.httpBasic().disable()`.

Why would this response come? Is there a better way to override the default basic auth configs? Is there an ordering on these configurations as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526644/spring-security-with-oauth2-or-http-basic-authentication-for-the-same-resource)? Where is this documented?

```
  ...env values

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain webFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.oauth2Client()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .disable()
      .formLogin()
      .disable()
      .csrf()
      .disable()
      .authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated();
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getClientRegistrationRepository() {
    ClientRegistration google =
        ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
            .scope("openid", "profile", "email")
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .authorizationUri(authUri)
            .tokenUri(tokenUri)
            .userInfoUri(userInfoUri)
            .redirectUri(redirectUri)
            .jwkSetUri(jwksUri)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .userNameAttributeName("name")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(google);
  }
```

Project on github: https://github.com/segevmalool/spring-samples/blob/main/spring-security-webflux-postgres

Comment: Adding the SecurityConfiguration class to the test's ContextConfiguration classes list "fixed" what I was seeing in the test context, but still not sure why the password is being generated.

Comment: this is impossible for us to know unless you provide a project that demonstrates the problem. My first question is, is your security configuration even loaded?

Comment: Added the project link, here's the line where I added the security config to the test context: https://github.com/segevmalool/spring-samples/blob/main/spring-security-webflux-postgres/src/test/java/com/segbaus/user/userTest.java#L16

The config is definitely loaded (when running), it works in the browser context like I mentioned. But I think the test context defined by `@WebFluxTest` is partial.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614553/spring-webflux-disabling-login)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31903939)